# Path to store generated file in the user desktop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in testing mode i am storing automated generated file in desktop using 
**"D:/users/Desktop/filename.xls**
what will be the link in production which file stored in respected user desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "path" to an arbitrary user's desktop. You can't read or store things on the user's desktop in Rails, or any other server-side framework. You have no access to the user's file system at all.

If you want to send the user a file, you need to serve it up via HTTP. If this is a generated file on disk, you can simply place it in `public` and link to it. Otherwise, you need to stream it to the user in a controller.